# using a derived class in layout.xml in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to implement a derived class in an Android app.
The class is derived from the ToggleButton widget. it looks something like this:

```
public class ButtonController extends ToggleButton implements OnClickListener{

    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean on;

    public ButtonController(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        enabled =false;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean en){
        enabled=en;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(enabled == true)
            on=!on;
    }
}
```

However how do I use this custom object in my layout.xml?
If i create just a normal ToggleButton and try

```
ButtonController b1 = (ButtonControllerfindViewByI(R.id.button1);
```

the application just crashes.

I also tried to make the object in layout.xml as follows:

```
<ToggleButton
                    class = "com.example.testv1.ButtonController"
                    android:id="@+id/Button1"
                    android:layout_width="100sp"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:textOn="Button 1 On"
                    android:textOff="Button 1 Off" />
```

but the application still stops unexpectedly when put on a device. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
<com.example.testv1.ButtonController
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:textOn="Button 1 On"
    android:textOff="Button 1 Off" />
```

Comment: do I still need to use the class attribute? Also generally, what  is the use of the class attribute?